# How to change version of Python in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I wanted to make Discord bot (should I even write this here), but it's said that I need Python 3.6, not Python 3.7 that I have.

How can I change from Python 3.7 to Python 3.6 to make something like that ?

Comment: you just need to change the Python Interpreter used for the project. Edit configurations/Python interpreter.

Comment: ... and install Python 3.6 if it's not already done

Comment: how does one downgrade pycharm version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First make sure you have Python 3.6 installed.

Then Go to `File > Settings > Project:* > Project Interpreter`, then select your interpreter under the `Project Interpreter` drop down.

If its still not there, you can also press the settings cog button [image] on the right side of the drop down and select `add`. Select `System Interpreter` from the left side, then select the interpreter from there. When you press `ok`, the interpreter will be available to be selected.

Comment: how does one downgrade pycharm version?

Answer (score 0):

in this order:

```
File---settings---project:xxx---project Interpreter--(choose your dir)
```

in the right have a project Interpreter,choose your python

Comment: When i go like that, there is only Python 3.7 for every project I have made up until now... :/

Comment: Well, yes, you've made a Virtualenv for every project, then, which is good practice. You need to **install** Python 3.6 (outside the IDE) if that's what you what to use, however Python 3.6 and 3.7 are not vastly different